# php mail works for all emails clients except laposte.net and hotmail.fr: how to fix that?

Tags: php, sendmail

I am using simple php script to send message

> ```
> $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
> $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
> $headers .= 'From: haveameet <noreply@haveameet.com>' . "\r\n";
> $headers .= 'Reply-To: noreply@haveameet.com' . "\r\n";
> mail('myemail@laposte.net', 'subjectr', 'message', $headers);
> ```

It works for gmail, outlook, yahoo
But just does not on laposte.net (which is a very popular french email).
It is not in spam folder either.

Website who send that email is a brand new who cannot be blacklisted: it was never used.

What may be the problem and how to solve that ?

When looking at mail.log I got

```
    Jan 26 17:37:35 sd-45956 sendmail[3578]: s0QGbZIq003578: from=www-data, size=116, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201401261637.s0QGbZIq003578@sd-45956.dedibox.fr>, relay=www-data@localhost
    Jan 26 17:37:35 sd-45956 sm-mta[3579]: s0QGbZQI003579: from=<www-data@sd-45956.dedibox.fr>, size=397, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201401261637.s0QGbZIq003578@sd-45956.dedibox.fr>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=loca$
    Jan 26 17:37:35 sd-45956 sendmail[3578]: s0QGbZIq003578: to=yarekc@laposte.net, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30116, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent $
    Jan 26 17:37:36 sd-45956 sm-mta[3581]: s0QGbZQI003579: to=<yarekc@laposte.net>, ctladdr=<www-data@sd-45956.dedibox.fr> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120397, relay=smtp4.laposte.net. [193$
    Jan 26 17:37:36 sd-45956 sm-mta[3581]: s0QGbZQI003579: s0QGbaQI003581: DSN: Data format error
    Jan 26 17:37:37 sd-45956 sm-mta[3581]: s0QGbaQI003581: to=<www-data@sd-45956.dedibox.fr>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent

in /var/mail/www-data I got

    From MAILER-DAEMON  Mon Jan 27 01:51:30 2014
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
        by haveameet.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4) id s0R0pUjg008124;
        Mon, 27 Jan 2014 01:51:30 +0100
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 01:51:30 +0100
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON>
Message-Id: <201401270051.s0R0pUjg008124@haveameet.com>
To: <www-data@haveameet.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="s0R0pUjg008124.1390783890/haveameet.com"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--s0R0pUjg008124.1390783890/haveameet.com

The original message was received at Mon, 27 Jan 2014 01:51:29 +0100
from haveameet.com [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<yarekc@laposte.net>
    (reason: 501 5.1.0 Emetteur invalide. Invalid Sender. LPN007_405 [405])

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to smtp4.laposte.net.:
>>> MAIL From:<www-data@62-210-238-225.online.net> SIZE=596
<<< 501 5.1.0 Emetteur invalide. Invalid Sender. LPN007_405 [405]
501 5.6.0 Data format error

--s0R0pUjg008124.1390783890/haveameet.com
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; haveameet.com
Received-From-MTA: DNS; haveameet.com
Arrival-Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 01:51:29 +0100

Final-Recipient: RFC822; yarekc@laposte.net
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 501 5.1.0 Emetteur invalide. Invalid Sender. LPN007_405 [405]
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 01:51:30 +0100

--s0R0pUjg008124.1390783890/haveameet.com
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers
```

I got:

```
host -t mx haveameet.com
haveameet.com mail is handled by 1 mx3.ovh.net.
haveameet.com mail is handled by 5 mx4.ovh.net.
haveameet.com mail is handled by 100 mxb.ovh.net.
```

Comment: What error code do you get ? What's your PHP email configuration ?

Comment: Email is a pain in the a**e. : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: do not get any error !

Comment: No, the issue is with the servers receiving the mail, they only accept mail that passes their criteria, see the link above

Comment: link is not related to php

Comment: I posted the mail.log

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a 550 back from them?

Comment: I am not sure about anything: I just post mail.log and php script. 
And I do not receive any mail in my mailbox

Comment: It says DSN: Data format error in your log file. What is your mail server saying its name is when connecting to remote mail servers? Is it showing the correct DNS name when sending mail?

Comment: "Data Format Error" - I assume, some header is missing or they want it in a different notation. Try to get a mail which has been approved  from your inbox and try to get the headers from that in order to reverse engineer.

Comment: Laposte.net have very stringent antispam requirements (much like AOL). You're probably failing reverse lookup or something.

Comment: there are email servers that just deny emails from dynamic ip addresses

Comment: Could you post bounce message received by www-data? Most likely it contains more details than the log file.

Comment: I don't receive ANY ERROR. I don't receive any bounds. I receive NOTHING. No error in php script, no error in mailbox. Looks like a DNS  problem. But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Bounce message regarding queue id `s0QGbZQI003579` has queue id `s0QGbaQI003581`.  `s0QGbaQI003581` has been delivered to local mailbox `www-data`. Have you inspected `/var/mail/www-data` mailbox file?

Comment: I have posted the content of /var/mail/boulier

Comment: btw.. your site has no security ;) You just hit "go" and are logged in.

Comment: We're looking at the wrong end. The above mail content is the failure to deliver the bounce message to www-data which has been sent by the local machine to the account bourlier. A "bounce of the bounce". Consider setting up an alias for www-data pointing to bourlier and start over.

Comment: I put hostname=haveameet.com and have now error  the /var/mail/www-data: I updated my question.

Comment: host -t mx haveameet.com
    haveameet.com mail is handled by 1 mx3.ovh.net.
    haveameet.com mail is handled by 5 mx4.ovh.net.
    haveameet.com mail is handled by 100 mxb.ovh.net.